# How to check if an item is the last one of iteration?

Tags: python, iteration

For example, I have a list of strings:

```
str_list =['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
```

I want to print all of them on the screen with:

```
for c in str_list:
    print c
    print ', ' # word separator
```

which results in:

```
one, two, three, four, five,
```

Here, a comma is not necessary at the end of the line and I don't want to print it. How can I modify the code above not to print the last comma?

It can be solved with `enumerate`:

```
for idx, c in enumerate(str_list):
    print c
    if idx < len(str_list) - 1:
        print ','
```

However, I think there may be a more elegant way to handle this.

Edited:
Maybe I thought I gave a too simple example. Suppose what if I should call function `x()` for each iteration except for the last one:

```
for idx, x in enumerate(list_x):
    if idx < len(list_x) - 1:
        something_right(x)
    else:
        something_wrong(x)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem with `if idx < len(list_x) - 1:` is that it only works with sequences and not more generically with any iterator. You could write your own generator that looks ahead and tells you whether you've reached the end.

```
def tag_last(iterable):
    """Given some iterable, returns (last, item), where last is only
    true if you are on the final iteration.
    """
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    gotone = False
    try:
        lookback = next(iterator)
        gotone = True
        while True:
            cur = next(iterator)
            yield False, lookback
            lookback = cur
    except StopIteration:
        if gotone:
            yield True, lookback
        raise StopIteration()
```

In python 2 it would look like:

```
>>> for last, i in tag_last(xrange(4)):
...     print(last, i)
... 
(False, 0)
(False, 1)
(False, 2)
(True, 3)
>>> for last, i in tag_last(xrange(1)):
...     print(last, i)
... 
(True, 0)
>>> for last, i in tag_last(xrange(0)):
...     print(last, i)
... 
>>>
```

Answer (score 8):

Inside of `', '.join(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'])` there's some sort of iteration ;)

And this is actually the most elegant way.

Here's another one:

```
# Everything except the last element
for x in a[:-1]:
    print(x + ', ', end='')

# And the last element
print(a[-1])
```

Outputs `one, two, three, four, five`

Comment: Well, that suits in this case, thanks. Maybe I thought I gave a too simple example. Suppose what if I should call function x() for each iteration except for the last one.

Answer (score 3):

I would do (you could do `join`, but it is unnecessary and this I think is much more elegant):

```
>>> print(*str_list, sep=', ')
one, two, three, four, five
```

Very few know about the optional `sep` argument in the `print` function- by default it is a whitespace. The `*` just unpacks the `list` into separate items to be printed.

**EDIT:**

For your example regarding a loop, you are checking a condition on each iteration, which is a bit silly.

Instead, just iterate up to the penultimate element (`range(len(a)) - 1`) and then when that loop is done only then call the `something_wrong()` function with the last element of `a` (`a[-1]`) as the argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't like the way using `enumerate` something. So I've posted this question and it seems it's the common and popular way.

Comment: I edited again, there are a few improvements that I would add, but don't let them bother you too much. One should get the entire code working first, and then worry about optimisation later. @Jeon

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a more generalized solution to skip the last element, then this might be useful:

```
a = ['a','b','c','d']
for element,_ in zip( a, range(len(a) - 1) ):
    doSomethingRight(element)
doSomethingWrong(a[-1])
```

*Explanation:*
`zip` will exit when the shorter of the lists is exhausted. So, by looping over `a` and a `range` one item shorter in length, you'll `doSomethingRight()` for all elements except the last one. Then call `doSomethingWrong()` for the last element.

In your example,

```
str_list = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
word_seperator = ","; string_end = "!"
result = ""
for element,_ in zip( str_list, range( len(str_list) - 1 ) ):
    result += element + word_seperator    # This is my 'doSomethingRight()'
result += str_list[-1] + string_end    # This is my 'doSomethingWrong()'
```

Result: `one,two,three,four,five!`

Hope this helps!